# How can I access the symfony Service Container in my Service?

Tags: symfony

I have created a new Service, and its job involves calling functions on other services that must be loaded *by name* at runtime. So, I can't pass in a static set of services to my service, I want it to actually be able to call `get()` on the service container itself. The Symfony docs haven't been helpful for describing how to do this outside of a Controller class where I can just call $this->get(). Anyone know how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two possible solutions :

**1. Inject the service container :**

```
<argument type="service" id="service_container" />
```

And then in your class :

```
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container;

//...

public function __construct(Container $container, ...) {
```

**2. Extend ContainerAware class**

```
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAware;

class YourService extends ContainerAware
{
    public function someMethod($serviceName) 
    {
        $this->container->get($serviceName)->doSomething(); 
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: You should not inject the `service_container` in your services. In your example you should rather inject only the services you need instead. See for example the "Avoiding your Code Becoming Dependent on the Container" section of http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection.html.